# Doing online business using fake profile

Tags: business

So, I have a friend which uses online fake ID on twitter to engage foreign customers and sell services (Logo & Website Designing) & this business is so profitable & I also want to get into it. But my question is it halal to do business using fake ID claiming that I am girl living in USA e.g?

Comment: any explanation of downvote?

Comment: Why would you think lying is halal under any circumstances?

Comment: Yes thanks, I don't think lying is halal in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **haram** because it involves cheating and lying, especially given that many people may have a good reason for wanting to know such information and rely on it in taking the decision to engage in a business transaction or not.

The Prophet, *sallallaahu ‘alayhi wa sallam*, said,

> "Both parties in a business transaction have a right to annul it so
> long as they have not separated; and if they tell the truth and make
> everything clear to each other, then they will be blessed in their
> transaction, but if they conceal anything and lie, then the blessing
> of their transaction will be eliminated."
> [Al-Bukhari and Muslim]

Here are also some of the references which helps you understand:

1. [Lying about identity to market product online](https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/332536/lying-about-identity-to-market-product-online)
2. [Darul Ifta, Darul Ulum Deoband Fatwa on getting job by telling a lie, cheating and showing false experience](https://darulifta-deoband.com/home/en/halal-haram/31486)
3. [Sheikh Assim Al Hakeem explaining about If someone gets a job with fake / false certificates, will his/her salary be haram?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rA4KEJd0LfQ)

I hope you will not join this type of business though it looks profitable.

Comment: @Ibnelaiq I want to know why my answer is not correct.

Comment: Because I forgot it to mark as correct. :)